# Javascript / CSS window.scrollTo(0,0) not working

Tags: javascript, css

I am building a web app, and part of that web app needs to scroll to the top when an action is performed. This is handled using `window.scrollTo(0,0)` which works perfectly until I add some CSS styling below (which I require for this project).

Has anybody got any idea why the CSS below would stop `window.scrollTo(0,0)` working?

```
* {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

P.S. I cannot use jQuery in my situation, just in case it's suggested that I do that.

Comment: use jQuery :) No, I tried what you said, and it works with me on FF, Chrome and IE. Can you post some more code?

Comment: If you're using material design sidenav see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43710010/2146647

Comment: try wrapping your `window.scrollTo(0, 0) inside a setTimeout, that works for me

Comment: For me remove `body{ height: 100%;}` solve this issue.

Answer (score 35):

I had the same problem, this fixed it:

`document.getElementById('ELEMENT_ID').scrollIntoView();`

Where `ELEMENT_ID` is the id of the object you want to scroll into view, in your case it would typically be the header.

Note this only works fully on Firefox browsers as the other browsers have yet to implement the smooth scrolling option (see more: http://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview).

Comment: Thanks, this is the only solution that worked for me. I now just need to work out how to nudge the scroll position down a little so that I can see the scrolled to element on the screen clearly.

Comment: Thanks! it works where the container is using 100vh

Comment: I can get the element but the scroll is not working.

Answer (score 14):

Try the alternative :

```
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
```

Answer (score 10):

I my case removing this block fixed the issue

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I also had an issue having a container element with 100vh and I had to remove it.

Comment: @Dima I have the same issue but I can't remove this above block. What shall I do? any suggestions?

Comment: @khush did you solve the issue? I'm running in the same problem where I can't remove the overflow-x: hidden

Answer (score 5):

Turns out there was not a set height on the main element in the body, which meant scroll to wasnt working however the transition CSS was giving the element height automatically in webkit.... Fixed the CSS to give it a set height and it works again!

Comment: Just had an issue with scrollTo not working, also down to the height not being set on the body element. Thanks for posting your final solution

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

to

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue recently in a Gatsby project. I had tried wrapping in setTimeout with no success.

What ended up working for me was `window.scrollTo(0, -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found also that adding the following CSS caused the `window.scroll()` and `window.scrollTo()` methods to have no effect.

```
body {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @basarat's answer. It worked perfectly!

I did it in React, but in a function it's working and has smooth scroll.

```
    const scrollToTop = () => {
      document.body.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
   };
```