# How to include anchor at the end of the link using routerlink?

Tags: angular, angular-router

How to include anchor at the end of the link using routerlink?

I need to include an anchor at the end of the link to be able to identify a particular location on the page that will be accessed.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/page', item.slug]#local"> Button </a>
```

Page

```
<a name="local"></a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autoscroll in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201624/autoscroll-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a [routerLink]="['/page', item.slug]#local"> Button </a>`

wont work fine.

You can refer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201624/autoscroll-in-angular-2)

Comment: Hi, The link that needs to be generated is: http://localhost/page#location

Comment: navigateMe() { this.router.navigate(['/page', item.slug, local]); }  ?

Comment: Anyways you can refer this one [link](https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/advanced/smooth-scroll/) hope this can help

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.